# Trying to implement loading spinner while loading data from Firestore with Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on an app that display spinner when backend loading data from Firestore but it's not worked as intended and I'm having a struggle to find the flaw.

My Orders Page code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:table_service/providers/order.dart';

import '../providers/session.dart';

class OrdersPage extends StatefulWidget {
  bool isLoading = true;

  @override
  _OrdersPageState createState() => _OrdersPageState();
}

class _OrdersPageState extends State<OrdersPage> {
  List<Order> _orders = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final session = Provider.of<Session>(context, listen: false);

    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: session.privilege == 'Administrator' ||
              session.privilege == 'Waiter' ||
              session.privilege == 'Customer'
          ? FloatingActionButton(
              heroTag: 'OrdersPageFAB',
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white),
            )
          : null,
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: session.fetchOrdersData(),
        builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          } else {
            print(snapshot.data);
            return GridView.builder(
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                childAspectRatio: 2 / 2,
              ),
              itemCount: _orders.length,
              itemBuilder: (_, i) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                  child: Card(
                    child: GridTile(
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.library_books,
                        size: 100.0,
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      ),
                      footer: GridTileBar(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
                        title: Text('Order by: ${_orders[i].name}'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The fetchOrdersData() handler

```
final Auth auth = Auth();
final Firestore database = Firestore.instance;

String user_name;
String privilege;

List<Food> _foods = [];
List<Order> _orders = [];
List<TransactionModel.Transaction> _transactions = [];

... 
...

Future fetchOrdersData() async  {
  _orders.clear();
  return await  database.collection('orders').getDocuments().then((documents) {
    documents.documents.forEach((order) {
      database
          .collection('users')
          .document(order.data['uid'])
          .get()
          .then((user) {
        _orders.add(Order(
          id: order.documentID,
          tableNumber: order.data['tablenumber'],
          orderDate: (order.data['orderdate'] as Timestamp).toDate(),
          status: order.data['status'],
          note: order.data['note'],
          uid: order.data['uid'],
          name: user.data['user_name'],
        ));
      });
    });
    return _orders;
  });
  notifyListeners();
}

get getOrders {
  return [..._orders];
}
```

I have tried many methods including StreamBuilder, setState() and recently FutureBuilder.
Did i just missing an important code?
Or did i use the wrong method?

The problem was Orders Page showing 0 data even though List on _fetchOrdersData() have 1 element.

for full source code
[here on github](https://github.com/hariyanuar/table_service)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers look reasonable. They are just missing data validation checks, which I find is required in all my apps. Because if I have a good connection, and hasData is true and hasError is false, there might be no documents at all though. This should be checked. Here is a snippet from my projects.

Checking connection state is the same as just checking snapshot.hasError.

```
Widget _getMyFriends() {
return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: Database.getFriendsByUserId(widget.loggedInUserId),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasError)
      return Center(child: Text("Error"));
    else if (!snapshot.hasData)
      return Center(child: Text("Loading..."));
    else if (snapshot.data.documents.isEmpty) //also check if empty! show loader?
      return Center(child: Text("No friends added yet."));
    else
      return ListView(
        children: snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
          return SimpleUserPanel(userId: document['friendid']);
        }).toList(),
      );
  }
);
```

}

Comment: my orders page shows 0 data, I think it caused by flawed asynchronous code when fetching data from firebase.

Comment: Your fetchOrdersData code needs to be re-written. You are mixing async await with chain .then promises, and adding them to a list afterwards etc. This is probably where 99% of the problem lies.

You should either want to display the data in a collection as-is, which is where you can use streambuilder. Alternatively you can download the data with a proper async await function on init (or button click etc.) do your logic and then display the data.

Comment: How would you handle this with the BLoC Pattern? I don't listen to the stream in the UI but in the Bloc and using states.

Comment: Sorry no idea, I never use that style with flutter, it looks like going back in time to old style of MVC/MVVM and other monolith styles, which is what reactive, microservice, component based styles like flutter/react was made to replace.

Answer (score 0):

You should do the following:

```
else {
         if(snapshot.hasData){
            print(snapshot.data);
            return GridView.builder(
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                childAspectRatio: 2 / 2,
              ),
              itemCount: _orders.length,
              itemBuilder: (_, i) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                  child: Card(
                    child: GridTile(
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.library_books,
                        size: 100.0,
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      ),
                      footer: GridTileBar(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
                        title: Text('Order by: ${_orders[i].name}'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
        // By default, show a loading spinner.
         return CircularProgressIndicator();
           },
```

So first check if `snapshot` has data using the property `hasData` and since this is asynchronous it will first execute the `return CircularProgressIndicator();` and then execute the `if` block.

Answer (score 0):

Loking at your code, you have to check for `ConnectionState.active` also with your `snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting`.

Actually you have more power and controll when using `FutureBuilder` or `StreamBuilder`. Below is a sample code snippet:

```
switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
    case ConnectionState.none:
      return Center(child: Text("Check Connection"));
    case ConnectionState.active:
    case ConnectionState.waiting:
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,));
    case ConnectionState.done:
      if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Center(child: Text("Error occured!"));
      } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return YourWidgetWithData();
      } else {
        debugPrint("What went wrong");
        return SizedBox();
      }
      break;
    default:
      return SizedBox();
  }
```